# Delete option in custom menu of jstree is not working as intended

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working on `jstree` in `php`, I've got the code from `phpflow`. However the delete option in the custom menu is not working as expected. When I try to delete the child node it is working fine. But when I try to delete the Parent node only few of its child nodes are getting deleted. Few other child nodes are belonging to the same parent are left out. Can any one of you assist me to solve this issue.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's not easy to help. Also, tag your question with relevant tags, it will attract more people who can help.

Comment: case 'delete_node':
        $node = isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] !== '#' ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;
                        $id=$_GET['id'];
      $nameQuery="select * from treeview_items where id='".$id."'   ";
      $result=mysql_query($nameQuery);
      $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
      $companyName=$row['name'];   
     $sql ="DELETE FROM `treeview_items` WHERE `id`= '".$node."'  OR `parent_id`= '".$node."' OR `name` = '$companyName'";
            
      
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    

      
            
        
        break;

Comment: here id is fetched from index.php

Comment: on('delete_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
          
         $.get('response.php?operation=delete_node', { 'id' : data.node.id})
          
            .fail(function () {
              data.instance.refresh();
              
              
              
            });

Comment: any suggestions would be helpful